# SocketsHttpHandler timeout not obeying the defined timeout

Tags: c#, httpclient

I am establishing a new connection like this:

```
var socketsHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler
{
    ConnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
};

var client = new HttpClient(socketsHandler);
```

However after 5 seconds I get a timeout:

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (localhost:8100)
> ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10061): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Comment: Active refusal is not a timeout. It doesn't have to wait 60 whole seconds to report that the server just isn't having it.

Comment: The machine is refusing a connection, ie replying with a TCP `RST` reset packet